# nodejs Async.parallel inside find().cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

I am performing several findOne() queries to a mongoDB while inside a cursor for 1 large mongoDB collection (~500MG).

I am doing:

```
var batchSize = 100;
var cursor = Col1.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: batchSize});
cursor.on('data', function (result) {
    var parm1 = result.parm1;
    var parm2 = result.parm2;
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            Coll3.findOne({a: parm1}).then(Col3Res=>{
               callback(Col3Res);
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            Coll2.findOne({a: parm2}).then(Col2Res=>{
               callback(Col2Res);
            });
        }
    ], function(err, results){

    });
});
```

vs:

```
var batchSize = 100;
var cursor = Col1.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: batchSize});
cursor.on('data', function (result) {
    var parm1 = result.parm1;
    var parm2 = result.parm2;

    Coll3.findOne({a: parm1}).then(Col3Res=>{
        Coll2.findOne({a: parm2}).then(Col2Res=>{
            callback();
        });
    });
});
```

Using the async.parallel inside the cursor takes longer than to nest the Coll3 and Coll2 findOne. Is this the expected behavior? What is the overhead on having the async.parallel inside the cursor?